# Building an elevated deck over 6x6x6 posts, a beam made of 3 pressure treated 2x8x16' is too narrow

Tags: deck, structural, decking

In building an elevated deck over 6x6x6 posts, a beam made of 3 pressure treated 2x8x16' (where the beams are attached to each other with FastenMaster ThruLoks) is too narrow (~5" versus 6" expected) for the galvanized-steel beam holder resting atop the post. I suppose this is due to nominal widths of the lumber, but I read this technique was acceptable if you could not get a beam and wanted to build it yourself with 2x8x16' pressure treated lumber.
Where did I go wrong and what can I do to keep doing this right?

[image: Beam Gap]
[image: Beam Gap]
[image: Beam Gap]
[image: System Before DIY beams]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the right size bracket isn't a problem, if you go to Simpson Strong Tie web site, or other comparable brand, you'll find a part number to fit your beam and post sizes.  [Look at the PCZ6](https://www.strongtie.com/onepiecepostcaps_postcaps/pcz-epcz_productgroup_wcc/p/pcz.epcz).  Or on this catalog page, the CC4.62-5.50:

http://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/ef6qdoh2bf/C-C-2019-p090-091.pdf

Just make sure that the built up beam you made is adequately sized for the load.  A built up  beam made from three 2x8's may be strong enough for your deck but it is not as strong as a 6x8 beam.

Comment: Your last statement seems to ignore the primary benefit of plywood. I'd bet that, on average, a compound beam would be stronger.

Comment: @isherwood - I don't see mention of plywood, it seems like the OP's plans called for a 3"x8" beam and he substituted a beam made of 3 2x8's, less wood, no plywood.

Comment: I was speaking generically with respect to laminated lumber of all sorts, such as LVL beams.

Answer (score 1):

If the beam of three 2x8s is sufficient for the load, consider filling out the space in the post connectors with sliced scraps of the 2x8s you used for the beam.

**EDIT** You could center the beam and put slices on each side.